# How to create realistic explosion in unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4, particle-system, blueprint, unreal-blueprint

I can create explosion like the one in starter content pack but it doesn't look that realistic and also I wanna create large explosion so how can I do that? Something like in Call of duty.
link to Tutorials would help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to learn to use the [Cascade Particle Editor](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/ParticleSystems/Cascade/). Unreal Engine has a [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gYDLyB3LVfjYIcbBe8NqR8t) on Youtube to get to learn it. From experience, jumping in to the engine and trying to make something like a realistic explosion won't be easy. I would suggest taking a look at the starter pack explosion to get an idea of what to do. Also, StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, not like this one. I would try over at [UE4 AnswerHub](https://answers.unrealengine.com/index.html) for broad questions like this.